# How to retrieve data from Symantec using their API?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Currently I am getting an error 400 status code

I am lost at what I need to do. Status code 400 is related to syntax. How do I format my output into JSON file format?

```
import requests, json, urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

url = 'https://symantecwebsite:8446/sepm/api/v1/identity/authenticate'
cert_location = 'newsymanteccert.cer'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

r = requests.post(url, verify=cert_location, auth=('myusername','password*-uTem'),
                  headers=headers)

print r.status_code
```

If I change the last line to print json.dumps, I get
    "function dumps at 0x03D349B0"

trying to get output from page 6 [https://symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/DOCUMENTATION/9000/DOC9447/en_US/REST_API_Ref_SEP14.pdf?**gda**=1499425764_2f09acf4cf9167a583f6e98bf13e44e0](https://symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/DOCUMENTATION/9000/DOC9447/en_US/REST_API_Ref_SEP14.pdf?__gda__=1499425764_2f09acf4cf9167a583f6e98bf13e44e0)

Comment: You don't need to use json.dumps the response has a json method. So just print r.json()

Comment: i wish it was that easy, i just tried that and got an error No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: So that means that your call isn't returning valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party, but I was having the same issue with almost the same python. SO, what my issue ended up being was the special characters in my password. The rest method that handles authentication on the Symantec manager side of things doesn't know how to handle certain special characters so it returns a 400 syntax error. Trying pulling special characters from you password, and keep it under 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be able to give you a full answer but I read through the PDF you linked. First step is to get a valid token from the chapter under **Authenticate to Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager**

e.g. "token": "c34692c5-201d-4d94-b0f8-61ed03383337"

My guess is you need to pass a dictionary:

```
urldata = {
"username" : "admin",
"password" : "password",
"domain" : ""
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"} # not 100% sure here but looks like you need to send headers too

response = requests.post(url, data = urldata, headers = heaaders) # gets data
rdata = json.loads(response.text) # loads data into a dictionary
mytoken = rdata["token"] # saves token to mytoken variable
```

Comment: i am working on this, i was able to get the output in json and then another error message, lol,  thank you!

Comment: where do i get this token?

Comment: I don't know if that works for this API but if it does the next step is using the token in a similar manner to get the responses you are after. But for future people it would also be helpful to update your question with the "right way". Update: **ok..** so you got an example only?

Comment: sorry, i didn't know i need a token, i am not sure where to get that

Comment: It is under the heading I wrote about. The url you get your token from is 'https://SEPM_IP:8446/sepm/api/v1/identity/authenticate' where SEPM_IP: SEPM_IP represents the IP address or the host name of the
Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager server.

Comment: sigh, this is so confusing, i can't get a token if i can't authenticate with my script

Comment: I agree... I normally find this things confusing but things eventually makes sense. This is a two-step process where you first get the token (using POST) and then use the token in a header (using POST) to get the desired results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148556/discussion-between-davidjbeiler-and-anton-vbr).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to just get the authentication:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import json

link ="https://YOUR_IP:8446/sepm/api/v1/"
data = { "username" : "admin", "password" : "password", "domain" : ""} #this is the login details required for the server
data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
urllib3.disable_warnings() #this is a patch to allow calls to SSL certs even if they cannot be verified
initialRequests = requests.get(link + "version", verify=False)


initialRequests = requests.post(link + "identity/authenticate", headers=headers, data=data, verify=False) #This requests an authentication from SEPM

api_token = (initialRequests.json()["token"]) #this uses the above line to get and store the token required for authenticated commands
```